# Annotating ambiguous type variable for MultiParamTypeClasses

Tags: haskell

I am working with a type class where I can "measure" some property of type `v` on an object of type `a`. For instance, consider the definitions below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

data SizedElem a =
  SizedElem
    { getSize :: Size
    , getElem :: Elem a
    }

newtype Size =
  Size Integer

newtype Elem a =
  Elem a

class Measured a v where
  measureTypeClass :: a -> v

instance Measured (Elem a) (SizedElem a) where
  measureTypeClass (Elem a) = SizedElem (Size 1) (Elem a)
```

Attempting to combine the functions for measuring the element and then extracting the size like so

```
broken :: Elem a -> Size
broken = getSize . measureTypeClass
```

results in a complaint from GHC:

```
Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘measureTypeClass’
prevents the constraint ‘(Measured
                            (Elem a) (SizedElem a0))’ from being solved.
...
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
These potential instance exist:
  instance Measured (Elem a) (SizedElem a)
```

Naively, I simply tried to annotate the type which I expect in the middle:

```
broken' :: Elem a -> Size
broken' xs =
  let meas = measureTypeClass xs :: SizedElem a
   in getSize meas
```

However, this results in a slightly different error:

```
No instance for (Measured (Elem a) (SizedElem a2))
  arising from a use of ‘measureTypeClass’
In the expression: measureTypeClass xs :: SizedElem a
In an equation for ‘meas’:
    meas = measureTypeClass xs :: SizedElem a
```

If I understand correctly, this means that the `a` interpreted from the annotation `:: SizedElem a` is not same type as the one in the type signature. How can I tell the compiler that these should be the same type variable? Simply applying `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` didn't solve the problem.

As an aside, everything works fine for a particular type, e.g.

```
specificWorks :: Elem Char -> Size
specificWorks xs =
  let meas = measureTypeClass xs :: SizedElem Char
   in getSize meas
```

or if the type signature has the same type variable for both the input and output

```
elemWorks :: Elem a -> Elem a
elemWorks = getElem . measureTypeClass
```

Additionally, forgoing the type class entirely also works, but for my actual application, I need the type class for other reasons:

```
measureDirect :: Elem a -> SizedElem a
measureDirect (Elem a) = SizedElem (Size 1) (Elem a)

directWorks :: Elem a -> Size
directWorks = getSize . measureDirect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the extension `ScopedTypeVariables`, add a `forall` quantifier to the function's signature:

```hs
getSize' :: forall a. Elem a -> Size
getSize' xs =
  let meas = measureTypeClass xs :: SizedElem a
  in getSize meas
```

Another technique that's applicable here is the ["constraint trick"](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/). A rule of thumb is to never have an instance head (to the right of `=>`) where a variable occurs twice, and to use an equality constraint instead.

```hs
instance (a ~ b) => Measured (Elem a) (SizedElem b) where
  measureTypeClass (Elem a) = SizedElem (Size 1) (Elem a)
```

Comment: That solved it! Thank you for pointing out the constraint trick as well. I wasn't aware of that, but it seems like a much better way to handle this type of problem in general